# postgres \copy file to RDS timeout

Tags: postgresql, copy

Postgres version 9.3, hosted on Amazon RDS.
I have a `messages` table with 10G of data.
I connected the database using `psql` on the EC2.
Then used

```
\COPY (select * from messages) TO '/tmp/messages.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, FORCE_QUOTE *)
```

to copy all messages into a file on the EC2.

Then I try to copy the file back to the table:

```
\COPY messages FROM '/tmp/messages.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV)
```

I always got this error after around 5 minutes. This `messages.csv` file is around 10G.

```
connection not open
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Succeeded.
```

I tried a dumb solution, to reduce the input data size, by spliting the file into multiple smaller trunks. ie 400MB each.

```
split -l 1000000 messages.csv messages_
```

This creates multiple smaller files with 400MB each. This works fine.

But is there any configurations I can change to keep the connections alive for large file?

I tried to set `tcp_keepalives_idle=7200` and `tcp_keepalives_interval=7200` and `tcp_keepalives_count=5`, but the connection still lost after 10-15 minutes.

Comment: This shouldn't happen. I'm wondering if there's an issue with your networking infrastructure. Have a look at the logs from the RDS instance to see what the server side saw when the connection broke. BTW, Amazon recommend that you `COPY` from S3 instead where possible.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the connection is between EC2 and RDS, I ssh to EC2, then on EC2 I use psql to connection to RDS. And I can only use the client version `\COPY` only, since I cannot connect to RDS directly to use the server version `COPY`.

Comment: `psql db_url < data.sql` Currently I am using this command, I modified the schema to include the trigger, then start restoring data seems fine, it did not disconnect at all.

Comment: Could you give us the result of `select name,setting from pg_settings where name like '%timeout%' order by name` ?